# Matlab: How to turn a vector of 2928x1 into a vector of 8784x1 with specific intervals of elements?

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, vector

I am trying to convert a vector with 2928 values into a vector with 8784 values. The first vector is a vector with info with an interval of 3hours, and I would like to have an hourly vector with those values added every 3 hours and the remaining should be filled with NaN. 
My first approach was to create a NaN vector with 8784 values but then I have not been able to create a 'for loop' that worked with this.

To make it simple, I'll try to explain with an example (n is the number of values of the smallest vector):

```
S_3h = ones(n,1); % this acts as the small vector that has only information each 3hours
B_h = nan(3*n,1); %this is the created hourly vector that I want to fulfill
```

The result wanted is:

```
B_h = [1 nan nan 1 nan nan 1 nan nan 1 nan nan ...]
```

Can you help me please?
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply index with step different to 1. In this case, step is 3.

```
B_h(1:3:end) = S_3h
```

Answer (score 1):

[Zizy Archer's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42902690/3372061) is good (and probably what you should use), but below is another option.

```
S_3h = ones(n,1);
B_h = nan(3,n); % notice the different indices

B_h(1,:) = S_3h; % the top row contains the non-NaN values. This is common to all methods.
B_h = B_h(:); % reshape to a column vector
```

Done a bit differently:

```
B_h = reshape( S_3h.' .* [1; NaN(1,2)],[],1);              % R2016b onward
B_h = reshape( bsxfun(@times, S_3h.',[1; NaN(2,1)]),[],1 ); % R2007a onward
```

If you have the image processing toolbox, you can also use the `padarray` function like so:

```
B_h = reshape(padarray(S_3h, [0 2], NaN, 'post').', [], 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are already two good answers, so just for the sport (and for the `kron`...), here is one liner solution:

```
S_3h = randi(10,1,n);
B_h=kron(S_3h,[1 NaN NaN]);
```